# MSSQL Query to get value between 1 month and a fixed day

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I can't managed to do it yet.

This is the idea:

```
select sum(amount) 
from  account
where amountdate >= 'CURRENTSYSTEMYEAR/CURRENTSYSTEMMONTH/10'  
   and amountdate <= 'CURRENTSYSTEMYEAR(+1 if it's december) / CURRENTSYSTEMMONTH + 1/10'
```

I know date queries don't work that way so I've using datepart and dateadd but didn't managed to do it.

As an example, if it is March 5, 2014, I want my date range to be March 10, 2014 to April 10, 2014.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: So for today, 2014-03-15, what date range are you looking for?  I can't understand fully from your question.  Is it from 2014-03-10 to 2014-04-10?

Comment: @user2989408. As I said mssql, microsoft sql server.
at Jason.  Yes, that's correct, but I wanna get it monthly so I always fetch monthly data.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to string and back to date:

```
select sum(amount)
from account
where amountdate >= convert(datetime, convert(varchar(8), getdate(), 120) + '10')
    and amountdate <= dateadd(month, 1, convert(datetime, convert(varchar(8), getdate(), 120) + '10'))
```

Here are the values:

```
select convert(datetime, convert(varchar(8), getdate(), 120) + '10')
-- 2014-03-10 today (2014-03-05)

select dateadd(month, 1, convert(datetime, convert(varchar(8), getdate(), 120) + '10'))
-- 2014-04-10 today (2014-03-05)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(amount) 
FROM  account
WHERE amountdate >= CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS CHAR(4))+'/'+CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS CHAR(2))+'/10' 
   and amountdate <= DATEADD(MM,1, CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS CHAR(4))+'/'+CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS CHAR(2))+'/10' )
```